# Kafka to Cloud Storage or BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, real-time

As a beginner and after using successfully Kafka, with Confluent, in the past months loading real-time data into GCP BigQuery.
I started to read more about real-time architecture approaches and noticed that there is also an option to move first the Kafka data to GCP Cloud Storage and then batch it into BigQuery.

Let me launch this discussion here - What are the [main] differences in moving Kafka real-time data into a BigQuery dataset against Cloud Storage?

Comment: GCS is cheaper and more accessible, but mainly for archival. Batching data between systems is definitely not real time. You could also export BQ to GCS instead, or duplicate data (in different formats, even) from Kafka Connect. So, what exactly is the goal you're solving?

Comment: Thank you, @OneCricketeer. 
My goal is to have different perspectives on why teams decide to stream their data to GCS and others to BigQuery directly. For example, you mentioned that GCS is more accessible - Could you kindly expand on this comment? Why is it more accessible? And who could take advantage of data in GCS instead of BigQuery? I like the idea of being cheaper for archiving data. Not interested in data batching.

Comment: GCS files can be exposed directly over HTTP, for example. Don't need to formulate a query for them or use custom clients. BQ is for analytics. If you just want to store data for yet undetermined purposes, you don't need BQ. If your data has no consistent schema, then you can't use BQ. But you can't keep data in Kafka, by default, due to retention, so it's written elsewhere in raw form, such as GCS.